# Custom font not working on live version of Laravel 9 Website

Tags: css, laravel, fonts, vite

**Problem**

So i've got a custom-font.ttf in my **public/fonts** directory 
 The font loads and works fine on local host. 
When deployed to heroku it's throwing a 404 error in console, and i noticed it's trying to access custom-font.ttf in **build/assets/fonts/..**

relevant part of app.css :

```
@font-face {
    src: url(/fonts/Satoshi-Variable.ttf);
    font-family: satoshi;
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';
```

**Question**

How do I make the live site use the font from public/fonts?

Or how do i add the font to vite properly so it includes it in the build folder?

Comment: Check this, maybe helps.  src: url('../fonts/Satoshi-Variable.ttf');

Answer (score 0):

Rather than force the app to look in a different folder, why not put it under your root src directory in a folder called assets? It should pick it up automatically then and put it where it belongs.